# PHP fgetcsv comma doublequote delimiter issue

Tags: php, csv

I can't seem to get PHP to correctly read in my CSV line with a comma inside of a double-quote delimiter ...

```
$fp  = fopen($strFName,'r');
// Read 1st line (title)
$csvline = fgetcsv($fp, 2048, ',', '"');
$strTit = $csvline[0];
```

*Normally I would just use fgetcsv($fp) and leave the defaults. But as it wasn't working properly I tried forcing the length and defaults.*

I know that the first line of my CSV file has the title. This has worked fine for tons of my CSV imports... now all of a sudden I get a title with a comma inside it. Excel creates the CSV file properly but fgetcsv does not seem to deal with it properly.

My title looks like this:

```
EU 2YO'S SIRES (Avg $30,000+)
```

In the CSV file, exported by Excel, my first line looks like this:

```
"EU 2YO'S SIRES (Avg $30,000+)",,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

My $strTit value ends up as:

```
"EU 2YO'S SIRES (Avg $30
```

The doublequote at the beginning is actually in the value and it stops at that first comma inside the doublequotes.

Comment: The defaults seem to work fine for me? ([Link](https://3v4l.org/VbH7p))

Comment: **ccKep** thank you for your example. You are using str_getcsv() rather than fgetcsv(). In my code, using fgetcsv(), I get the results as shown...

Comment: They use the same parsing method internally ([str_getcsv](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L5301) and [fgetcsv](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L2090) both internally use [php_fgetcsv](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L2094)). What I'm trying to say is: There might be a problem somewhere else in your code but without showing us a (reproducible) example or code we can't help you.

Comment: `fgetcsv` has a problem with BOMs, which make it fail to correctly read the first line. Maybe this is the case here, if you only see this problem in the title line. [See this comment](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php#122696).

Comment: Thank you **Karsten** that appears to be precisely the problem. I move the title to the second line of the CSV, and ignore the first, and all works perfectly. Now that I'm aware I can forever workaround. Thank you!